# Powershell - Move Mail

Tags: powershell, email, outlook

I'm newbie to powershell, and I have a challenge on process my script. It did everything perfectly, but it wont move the message to the target folder and I don't know why.

I thought maybe to process at end cycle, but the issue is that I can encour that will transfer also file that have not any reference, and I would avoid to process something that I have no info about.

I tried this

```
$MailboxName = "fatture@abc.com"
write-host "Now Processing" -ForegroundColor Yellow
write-host "Searching on Fatture" -ForegroundColor Yellow
$olFolderInbox = 6
$outlook = new-object -com outlook.application; 
$namespace = $outlook.GetNameSpace("MAPI"); 
$recipient = $namespace.CreateRecipient($MailboxName)
$inbox = $namespace.GetSharedDefaultFolder($recipient,6) 
$messages = $inbox.Folders.Item("Carriers").folders.Item("Gpac").folders.item("BLR")
$MoveTarget = $inbox.Folders.Item("Carriers").folders.Item("Gpac").folders.item("BLS")
$filepath = "C:\temp\FATTURE\Automation\" 

$messages.Items | % {
               
               Write-Host "New Message " $_.Subject
               $msg = $_
               $Ref = $_.Subject -replace ' ',''  
               $RefStr = $ref.split('#')
               $SearchSTR = $RefStr[2]
               write-host $SearchStr
       
             #  $invNbr = $body.Substring($body.IndexOf("INVOICE NO")+19,10)
             
               
               #write-host "The Invoice Number is : $invNbr" -ForegroundColor Cyan
               write-host "Querying for  $SearchSTR" -ForegroundColor Green
               $t = (Query_file($SearchSTR))[-1].CONSOL_REF
               write-host "File Found : $t" -ForegroundColor Cyan
               write-host $t
               if ($t -ne $null) {
               $filetype = $t.Substring(0,1)
               $date = Get-Date -format "yyyyMMddhhmmss"
               write-host "Today is Date is $date" -ForegroundColor Red
               Switch($filetype.tostring())
               {
                 {($_ -eq 1) -or ($_ -eq 2) -or ($_ -eq 7) -or ($_ -eq 7) -or ($_ -eq 8) }{($dept = "0001"), ($dept1 =  "ZLAG")}
                 {($_ -eq "F") -or ($_ -eq "V") -or ($_ -eq "M")}{($dept = "0002"), ($dept1 =  "Zero"), ($type  = "MOR")}
                 {($_ -eq 3) -or ($_ -eq 5) -or ($_ -eq "J")} {($dept = "0028"), ($dept1 =  "One"), ($type  = "OBR") }
                 {($_ -eq 9)} {($dept = "0031"), ($dept1 =  "CONSOLE")}
               }
               write-host "The  KEY TYPE is $dept1 " -ForegroundColor Yellow
               $fileStr = $t + "_INV_" + $dept + "_$date_.tsk"
               write-host " FILE Path: " $fileStr -ForegroundColor Cyan
               $msg.attachments | ?{$_.filename -like "*.pdf"} | %{
                              $file = $filestr
                              $_.saveasfile((Join-Path $filepath $filestr))
                              }

                $msg.UnRead = $false
                $msg.Move($MoveTarget)
                
               }
            #fine cycle messages
   
              
}
```

I tried to move from the cycle but the issue is that it goes for all of email, instead, I want to process only the email that should be. I would like when the attachment has being downloaded, that the email will be moved.

Comment: Try debugging the script in PowerShell ISE. Set breakpoints (F9) and step through the code line-by-line to see what it does at each point.

Comment: Another tip: `($_ -eq 1) -or ($_ -eq 2) -or ($_ -eq 7) -or ($_ -eq 8)` is written shorter as `1,2,7,8 -contains $_`

Comment: change the commas into semi-colons inside the switch blocks like: `{($dept = "0001"), ($dept1 =  "ZLAG")}` --> `{$dept = "0001";  $dept1 =  "ZLAG"}`

Comment: Thank you Theo, but in my case the Switch works well, my error comes from $msg.move that wont move to the target folder the selected email

Comment: What is the exact error raised by Move?

Comment: That is not movin the email. The email remains where it is, without moving on the target fld.

Comment: there is not any error, it simplty don't move the message.